# How to seamlessly upgrade webkitgtk in Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, 20.04, debian

Webkitgtk has released latest stable version 2.30.0 https://webkitgtk.org/2020/09/11/webkitgtk2.30.0-released.html
However I dont see the same version updated in ubuntu 18.04 and ubuntu 20.04 repository
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/webkit2gtk

I see there is debian package in https://packages.debian.org/experimental/amd64/libwebkit2gtk-4.0-dev/download

However when installing this there are lot of dependencies

Can we install webkitgtk and all its dependencies seamlessly

Comment: @user535733 Since 20.10 is not released yet,can it be backported to 20.04 atleast,last stable version of webkitgtk was backported as well

Comment: I stand corrected: Maybe it will be backported, maybe not. Looks like it's done by the Ubuntu Security Team, so [see the answer on their FAQ](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/FAQ#webkit)

Comment: @user535733 Do you have suggestion on how to upgrade

Comment: One way: Be patient. Running 20.10 packages today on older systems is a sure way to break them.

Comment: Related: [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/q/151283/816190)

Comment: @Kulfy Given that 20.10 is not released yet,could it be backported to 20.04 and 18/04? Do u have suggestions to upgrade webkitgtk

Comment: I don't know any resource which lists packages that would be backported. So, I have no idea. Also, as per [Ubuntu Package Search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=webkit2gtk&searchon=names&suite=groovy&section=all), 2.30 is not in 20.10 either. The [debian package page](https://packages.debian.org/experimental/amd64/libwebkit2gtk-4.0-dev/download) which you linked also mentions "*This package is from the experimental distribution. That means it is likely unstable or buggy, and it may even cause data loss.*". So, I think it's not the time to upgrade any way.

Comment: @Kulfy 2.30 is the stable version released by webkitgtk,actually 2.29.92 is unstable release